# Django Admin Model Schema

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

New to django, and loving it so far. I have a django admin, schema design question. I have a app that has a customer, product and order table. The customer has an order sheet of products, pre-built by admin, and saved in the CustomerProduct table. When the customer logs in they can only view their order sheet, update quantities, and that's it. They won't have access to products table or other customers order sheets. Three parts where im stuck right now,

1. The order table should have a many-to-many relationship with the customer_products table.
2. Order history needs to be saved in a separate table somehow, so if a user's order sheets changes, we still have record of their past orders. I need to construct a view for a user that will display just their order sheet. /admin/onlineordering/ordersheet.
3. How can I set this url up and limit access to a authenticated user. User A can only see User A's CustomerProduct (Order Sheet)

Below is the apps models.py and the admin.py

onlineordering/models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Customer(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, limit_choices_to={'groups__name': "customers"})
    customer_product = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through='CustomerProduct')
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.company_name

class CustomerProduct(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey('Customer')
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')

class Product(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description

class Order(models.Model):
    customer_product_order = models.ManyToManyField('CustomerProduct', through='CustomerProductOrder')
    purchase_order_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person_placing_order = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    requested_delivery_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

class CustomerProductOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey('Order')
    customer_product = models.ForeignKey('CustomerProduct')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

onlineordering/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .models import Order,Customer,Product

UserAdmin.add_fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'groups')}
    ),
)

class CustomerProductInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Customer.customer_product.through
    extra = 0

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        CustomerProductInline,
    ]

class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        CustomerProductInline,
    ]
    exclude = ('customer_product',)

admin.site.register(Order)
admin.site.register(Customer,CustomerAdmin)
admin.site.register(Product)
```

**Update**

/onlineordering/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def ordersheet(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world.")
```

/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url(r'^admin/onlineordering/ordersheet', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ]
```

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of that sql schema.

Comment: You are right, it doesnt need to be there. Removed.

Comment: You mean that you want to do it in the Django's built-in Admin, or in your own views?

Comment: If it can be done in the built admin that would be good. I'm looking into build custom admin views right now, and I guess I need to create an action, that user role has access to.

Comment: actually, ignore that, i'm thinking cakephp controller actions. I want to be able to setup routing for /admin/onlineordering/ordersheet, and it displays current logged in customer order sheet. And then create a permission for that function.